# Как бороться с некачественными вопросами?

Tags: поддержка, faq, модерация, вопросы

Время от времени в сообществе публикуются так называемые "некачественные сообщения". К ним можно отнести:

- спам - сообщения, опубликованные с целью поставить ссылку на внешний ресурс;
- пиар - сообщения, явно или неявно рекламирующие какой-либо товар или услугу;
- сообщения не соответствующие тематике Stack Overflow на русском, то есть не относящиеся к программированию, к системному администрированию или настройке сложного ПО;
- неуместные высказывания, например, рассуждения вида, есть ли жизнь на Марсе;
- невежливые и тем более оскорбительные замечания;
- нарушающие авторское право сообщения, например, вопросы о том, где бесплатно скачать  платный софт или книги;
- запутывающие, ложные сообщения, намеренно уводящие в сторону;
- предложения или просьбы сделать работу за деньги или безвозмездно.

Мы полагаем, что вопросы подобного рода обладают крайне низким качеством и как таковые должны либо исправляться, либо закрываться, либо удаляться.

Как правильно бороться с плохими вопросами?

1. Исправить вопрос, если это возможно.
2. Проголосовать против.
3. Просигналить тревогой.
4. Закрыть тему.

Как не стоит реагировать?

1. Комментировать умственные способности автора.
2. Отправлять в поисковик.
3. Издеваться и принижать автора.

Одной из главных задач Stack Overflow на русском является помощь в повседневной профессиональной деятельности - когда сообщество дает дельные ответы на качественно заданные вопросы. При этом простой вопрос не является плохим, он является простым.

Если Вы видите плохой, по вашему мнению вопрос, проголосуйте против, нажмите тревогу или закройте его. Так мы сможем сделать сообщество более "чистым".

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, нужно подавить их массой качественных. Отметили тревогой плохой вопрос - и сразу напишите хороший. Можно сразу с ответом.

Серьезно, пока у нас немного задающих вопросы - давайте делиться знаниями впрок в формате Q&A.

> Если же вопрос или ответ старые, и уже успели насобирать кучу плюсов, то в минусовании нет абсолютно никакого смысла. Их никто и никогда не увидит,

Да в общем-то как раз их и увидят. Вопрос будет в топе по своему тегу или ключевым словам. Как раз к популярным и наплюсованным вопросам нужно быть строже. Если получается - отредактировать и улучшить. Если совсем никак и вопрос не соответствует текущим правилам - удалять.

Comment: IMHO чем меньше трогать старые вопросы -- тем лучше.

Answer (score 4):

Поговорим об исключениях.

1. Отправлять в поисковик — это *правильное* решение. Разумеется, не в виде *google://{заголовок-вопроса}* или вовсе *lmgtfy://{заголовок-вопроса}*. Часто пользователь банально не может догадаться до правильных ключевых слов, и это далеко не всегда из-за глупости.

   Например, совершенно неочевидно, что "прозрачность элемента управления для событий мыши" переводится как "click through", а не "opacity". В этом случае даже перечисления ключевых слов будет достаточно, чтобы автор вопроса смог справиться со своей задачей. Конечно, с приложенным решением ответ будет гораздо лучше.
2. Объяснять автору, что он ни черта не смыслит в вопросе — это *правильное* решение. Разумеется, не в виде "ОП — идиот и не лечится", а с разбором критических ошибок, направления на путь истинный и советом курить маны.

   Я могу трижды презирать формулировки Полковника Шрапнеля и ликовать о его бане, но, чёрт побери, он умеет писать качественные ответы, которые действительно решают проблему. Если он говорит, что использовать *mysql_real_escape_string* для экранизации значений — это неверный подход, даже если код работает и нет уязвимостей, может, всё-таки стоит прислушаться?
3. Исправлять вопрос, полностью меняя значение, если на вопрос нет качественных ответов — это *неправильное* решение. Если пользователь пришёл за ответом на какой-то вопрос, то не надо игнорировать вопрос и отвечать на что-то, что соответствует правилам сайта, но не нужно автору. Этот автор завтра придёт и исправит текст назад. Или вообще отвандализирует текст. И что уж точно — ничему не научится.

   Полное изменение смысла вопроса лучше оставить для тех случаев, когда отдельные личности решили ответить на некачественный вопрос, автор на свой вопрос или плюнул, или удовлетворился ответом на "похожий" вопрос — в целом, когда система нормально не отработала, но уже есть полезный контент, который имеет смысл спасти. Аналогично и со старыми некачественными вопросами с качественными ответами — в этом случае автор точно не будет мешать и возмущаться.

   Если же хочется просто поделиться знаниями, то для этого есть более подходящий способ: задать свой вопрос, написать свой ответ — это вам даст полную свободу в выборе формулировок и избавит от претензий со стороны оригинального автора.
4. Голосовать против старых некачественных вопросов и ответов — это *неправильное* решение. Ну или абсолютно пустая трата времени, если точнее. Пока пост свежий, пока автор следит за его судьбой — оценки очень важны, потому что они служат прекрасным кнутом и пряником. Важно научиться голосовать не только за ответы, но и за вопросы, потому что это в большой степени влияет на наполнение сайта и на поведение участников.

   Если же вопрос или ответ старые, и уже успели насобирать кучу плюсов, то в минусовании нет абсолютно никакого смысла. Их никто и никогда не увидит, они абсолютно никак не повлияют на содержание сайта. В лучшем случае автор увидит "−2" в компании с очередным пополнением репутации "+10" или "+5" — если он сайт ещё не забросил. Скорее всего, реакции никакой не последует.

Некачественные ответы и некачественные вопросы без качественных ответов следует испепелять всеми возможными способами. Для этого в арсенале есть (в порядке возрастания эффективности):

- Тревоги. Сообщение отправляется в очередь (некачественную или сразу закрывательную — зависит от использованной тревоги) и/или к модератору напрямую.
- Голоса за закрытие. На сообщение навешивается голос, и оно отправляется в очередь на закрытие.
- Голоса за удаление. У большого количества пользователей достаточно привилегий, чтобы не только закрывать, но и удалять. Этим надо пользоваться активнее.

(Иногда тревоги бывают эффективнее, но я пока не определился.)

Comment: Если прямо куча плюсов на вопросе или ответе — то увидят, он же в топе висит.