# Стоит ли править "не серьезные вопросы"?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правки

Стоит ли участникам сообщества править "не серьезные вопросы", типа, "Дам немного больше инфы", "Вот тут у меня есть такая штучка", "челик с работы сказал сделать так..."? Как относится к таким вопросам?

Comment: Ну, если правка «не серьёзного» вопроса сделает его «серьёзным», то почему бы нет?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы имеете ввиду, можете привести более конкретный пример?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ссылаясь на вопрос [Как бороться с некачественными вопросами?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418/339283)

> Время от времени в сообществе публикуются так называемые
>   "некачественные сообщения".
>
> Мы полагаем, что вопросы подобного рода обладают крайне низким
>   качеством и как таковые должны либо исправляться, либо закрываться,
>   либо удаляться.
>
> Как правильно бороться с плохими вопросами?
>
> 1. Исправить вопрос, если это возможно.

---

Первое, что можно и нужно сделать с некачественным вопросом - это постараться править его. Если же правка ему навряд ли поможет, то Вы также можете:

> 2. Проголосовать против.
> 3. Просигналить тревогой.
> 4. Закрыть тему.

Как не стоит реагировать?

> 1. Комментировать умственные способности автора.
> 2. Отправлять в поисковик.
> 3. Издеваться и принижать автора.

---

> Одной из главных задач Stack Overflow на русском является помощь в
>   повседневной профессиональной деятельности - когда сообщество дает
>   дельные ответы на качественно заданные вопросы. При этом простой
>   вопрос не является плохим, он является простым.
>
> Если Вы видите плохой, по вашему мнению вопрос, проголосуйте против,
>   нажмите тревогу или закройте его. Так мы сможем сделать сообщество
>   более "чистым".